# Generate TypeScript interface from OData $metadata

Tags: typescript, odata, code-generation

I'm getting into OData and TypeScript and it struck me when learning about [OData Client Code Generator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx) that something similar could be done for getting TypeScript interfaces for OData endpoints. Would really help when refactoring :)

So was wondering if anyone got some experience on the matter. Like what tools they use. (if any exist)
Problems they encountered.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything but of course you could write some t4 templates to do it. If you do come up with anything, please share :)

Comment: http://type.litesolutions.net/  could be the tool you are looking for.

Comment: This questions quite old but [this](https://github.com/FuryTechs/FuryTech.OdataTypescriptServiceGenerator) may be of use to someone in the future

Comment: @RafaelCichocki while ts-odata is cool and helps you write the odata queries. It doesn't help you generate the model from the $metadata so you'll still be using magic string property names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [odata2ts](https://odata2ts.github.io/docs/generator/setup-and-usage/)

1. Configure `./odata2ts.config.ts`

```
import { ConfigFileOptions, Modes } from "@odata2ts/odata2ts";

const config: ConfigFileOptions = {
  mode: Modes.models,
  services: {
    metadata: {
      source: "odata_metadata.xml",
      output: "odata/metadata",
    },
  }
}

export default config;
```

2. Export your server's metadata file into `./odata_metadata.xml` (Example: [TripPin.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OData/ODataSamples/master/Components/Common/Model/TripPin.xml))
3. Generate types

```
npx odata2ts
```